# Copy & Paste with c#

Tags: c#

For example right now, when you click left mouse and choose paste (if enable) if it is file,or text string or picture etc you can understand somewhere in RAM its already handled or stored, how can i reach that area with C#. And how can i store something (text,picture,file) there.
I mean

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string message = "copy_me";

        DoIt(message);

    }

    private void DoIt(string msg_arg)
    {

        // msg_arg argument will be copied in a txt file
    }
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Copy

```
Clipboard.SetDataObject("String to copy");
```

Paste

```
IDataObject iData = Clipboard.GetDataObject();
```

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for the `Clipboard` class.

Answer (score 0):

Look at this [Clipboard](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.clipboard.aspx) class